# Prevent file deletion from firebase storage

Tags: firebase-storage

I read the whole storage documentation about security & rules and didn't found any example preventing a user to delete an existing file in firebase storage.

I tried by using crc32 and resources like below, but it didn't seem to work properly :

```
allow write: if request.resource.crc32c == resource.crc32c; // doesn't work (cannot create a new resource)
allow write: if request.resource; // doesn't work (cannot create a new resource) either
```

It would surprise me that it isn't achievable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved by checking resource size :

```
allow write: if request.resource.size > 0
```

Answer (score 4):

A better way would be

```
allow write: if request.auth != null && request.method != 'delete' && request.method!= 'update';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
       allow read: if false
       allow write: if request.method != 'delete' && request.method!= 'update';
       }
    }
}
```